# Generic Memory Pool - How to? - Design Issue

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, new-operator, memory-pool

I am creating my own memory pool for small and very frequently used objects. I am good with the allocation and d-allocation itself.

Here is layout of my Pool

```
class CPool
{ 
    unsigned int        m_uiBlocks;     
    unsigned int        m_uiSizeOfBlock;    
    unsigned int        m_uiFreeBlocks; 
    unsigned int        m_uiInitialized;    
    unsigned char      *m_pMemStart;        
    unsigned char      *m_pNext;            

    public:
            CPool();
            ~CPool();

            void                CreatePool(size_t sizeOfEachBlock,  unsigned int numOfBlocks);
            void                DestroyPool();

            unsigned char*      AddrFromIndex(unsigned int i) const;
            unsigned int        IndexFromAddr(const unsigned char* p) const;

            void*               Allocate();
            void                DeAllocate(void* p);
};
```

I would want each class to have its own pool. Now, if some class needs to use this pool, it is needed that

1. They call `CreatePool()` with size and no_of_objects
2. They either call parameterised `new` & `delete` or overload operators and call `Allocate` and `DeAllocate` functions from those.
3. call 'DestroyPool()'

I am more worried about calls like `Derived *derObj = new (poolObj)Derived();`. Here user may forget `poolObj` and that object will not be on my heap at all. Of course, for this to work I have global function like

```
inline void* operator new(size_t size, CPool&  objPool)
{
    return objPool.Allocate();
}
```

So I would want to ask specific questions:

1. How do I re-design my pool class so that if client calls 
   `Derived *derObj = new Derived();` I have a chance to allocate memory from my pool. Is it even possible?
2. Is there way to recognize `type` of object? So that `CreatePool` and
   `DestroyPool` can also be removed from client code? But I would need to be very careful that there is only one pool per 'type'.

I am ready to use templated code as well, but I am not sure what to templatize. Please suggest.

Comment: You can overload new, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new, but honestly, that seems way out of scope for what you need. In the end, we can't really make good design decisions on what you will use this for...as it states, you can allocate and deallocate exactly one type (and none of its derivations), which makes me wonder why the end user wouldn't just rather use std::vector<T> and give T a zombie state.

Comment: I am experimenting to see if I get any performance gain. This is for my OpenGL particle engine. I know MS implementation of C++ 11 that they increase memory by power of two so yes, I agree vecors should suffice, but still I wonder how the design might look like?

Comment: You are right on money, not getting anything from this Custom Pool. Vectors beat me badly..:D:D. Though I am better off with new and delete. I just felt what optimized code means.. I am allocating one big chunk of memory only once and alloating from that. Vectors(MS specific) on the other hand reallocate in order of 2^alloc_index which grows like 1, 2, 4, 8 16, 32 and so on.. but still they beat my code soo badly. I wanna learn more of this programming..