# operator delete - how to implement?

Tags: c++, memory-management, new-operator, delete-operator

I know in normal circumstances how to take care of memory de-allocation. My case is little different.

I am implementing my own memory pool. I would want client of my class to be as near to general method of allocation and de-allocation.

```
inline void* operator new(size_t dead_param, CPool&  objPool)
{
    return objPool.Allocate();
}
```

i have this global function, so that user of my class can simply call

`Base baseObj = new (poolObj)Base2();`

Now I don't know how to call destructor? I clearl have NO IDEA

though I have global operator delete

```
inline void operator delete(void* ptr, CPool& objPool)
{
    objPool.DeAllocate(ptr);
}
```

please guide.. how can i get this function called from client code? With minimal changes to syntax from user side. Also note I do not want users of my code to implement `operator new` and `operator delete` and call `Allocate` and `DeAllocate` from there.

Comment: Why not just have people call `Base* baseObj = poolObj.Allocate();`

Comment: Syntax for client seems little ugly. `Base* baseObj = (Base*) poolObj.Allocate()`. Yuck.. typecasting... that though I have kept as final resort.. Also since not able to get this function called, I am curous now..

Comment: Placement delete is only ever called from inside placement new, when a constructor exits with an exception. In all other cases, a "normal" `operator delete(void*)` is called. You are supposed to stash sufficient information into the allocated memory block to be able to deallocate it later, with no additional input. Often, the allocator would write additional information at the negative offset from the pointer it returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short of it: With placement new is the only case where explicitly calling the destructor is OK:

baseObj->~Base();

But this seems wonky because, with your memory pool, you're actually making the end user do all the book keeping...this makes your memory pool class no better (and arguably a little worse) than just using a std::vector.

I would not have the user do the placement new themselves...rather, if supplying your own memory pool, it should be done withing the ObjectPool class:

```
class ObjectPool {
  public:
    template <typename T, typename... A>/*c++ 11 ftw*/
    T* allocate(A... args) {
       void* create_location;//pool figures out where this is, probably with sizeof<T>

       return new (create_location) T(args...);
     }
     template <typename T>
     void dellocate(T* t) {
         t.~T();//With placement new, this is the one place this is OK
         //pool marks that memory as avaiable to be allocated in
     }
 }
```

Honestly, this is the only way for your pool to have any more utility then the end user just making their own `std::vector<uint8_t>`.

It should be noted that this does nothing to keep T from allocating anything else on the heap...

Comment: ok.. probably you can enlighten me more on design question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27375620/generic-memory-pool-how-to-design-issue I am not completely getting what you are trying to say